# How to do that int variable which obtains data through textbox gets displayed in a double-quoted format in the txt log file?

Tags: c#

> I try to write a log file and have created a desktop app containing
>   two textboxes and one button. I want int variables to be displayed in
>   the double-quoted style in the txt file. I tried to Convert
>   $"{textBox1.Text}\"" to the int in the assignment process but to no
>   avail - got the format exception error. So how to do that int variable
>   gets displayed as double marked in the txt file?

```
string username =  $"\"{textBox1.Text}\"";
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Cavid\Desktop\LogFiles\" +DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ".txt", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " " +username+ " has typed as username \r\n");

int password = Convert.ToInt32($"\"{textBox1.Text}\"");
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Cavid\Desktop\LogFiles\"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ".txt", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " " +password+ " has typed as password\r\n");
```

Comment: In your description you write that you are trying to convert `textbox2.Text`, but in your code it's `textBox1.Text`.

Comment: just a spelling mistake

Comment: Do you really expect *password* being an *integer* only (e.g. `123`)? What if user wants `MyPassword123` as a password?

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko this is not a project of course. I'm just learning to write a log file with this easy simple example

Answer (score 1):

> I'm simply trying to keep variables in the double-quoted format

Sorry, but you have to seem a wrong idea of how variables and data types work. An integer variable is just a 32 bit piece of memory with no quotes, or other formatting.

You simply can't assign or parse (without custom parse strings) a double quoted text to an integer. Stop trying that. Use this instead:

```
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int password))
{
    // text is a valid int, use `password`
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to softcode any double-quoted integer through textbox, it's all about the way it's stored as event in the log. Like : User has typed "767" as password . Double quote is supposed to be shown inside the txt file

Comment: What do you mean with "softcode"? If you want to show it *as text*, it should be *text*, not an integer.

Comment: it worked as code written like this : File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Cavid\Desktop\LogFiles\" +DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ".txt", $"\"{textBox1.Text}\""+ " has typed as password \r\n");

Comment: I see no string to integer conversion there.

Comment: as I said before my aim is to record an event - password written by the user, as in double quoted format in the txt file. If I type 123 as password through textbox it should be written as "123" in the txt file. So this code inside AppendAllText *$"\"{textBox1.Text}\"* did it for me

Answer (score 0):

To add double quotes use the following code:

string username = textBox1.Text;
            //add double quote

```
        username = "\"" + username + "\"";

        //you can test it as shown below
```

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\text2.txt", username);

For the error, you are getting as others also mentioned you cannot convert all of string s to an integer( For example if your username is alphanumeric)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want *password* being *integer* only? User is allowed to have `123` password only, but not, say, `a;sldf123_'vdkdm`?
More natural choice is get the password (let it be in `textBox2.Text`) as it is:

```
 string fileName = Path.Combine(
   @"C:\Users\Cavid\Desktop\LogFiles",             // Directory
   $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}.txt");  // File Name

 // Do not call DateTime.Now twice: you may have different times for username and password
 DateTime moment = DateTime.Now;
 string prefix = $"{moment.ToShortDateString()} {moment.ToShortDateString()}"; 

 // It seems you want textBox2.Text, not textBox1.Text as a password (typo?) 
 string[] lines = new string[] {
   $"{prefix} \"{textBox1.Text}\" has typed as username",
   $"{prefix} \"{textBox2.Text}\" has typed as password",
 };

 // Append file once
 File.AppendAllLines(fileName, lines);
```

If you insist on having integers as a password only, add `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse`:

```
 ...

 string[] lines = new string[] {
   $"{prefix} \"{textBox1.Text}\" has typed as username",
   $"{prefix} \"{int.Parse(textBox2.Text)}\" has typed as password",
 };

 ...
```